# Is the "Apple ID" in iTunesConnect different from "App ID" in developer.apple.com?

Tags: ios, app-id

In iTunesConnect.apple.com under "App Information" > "Identifiers" I see an "Apple ID".

In developer.apple.com under "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" > "Identifiers" > "App IDs" I see a "Prefix".

These two identifiers seem similar in style though the former is 9 characters and the latter is 10. Are they supposed to be different or the same value? What is the purpose of each? Why do we need two separate IDs for the same app? At what point in the development cycle do they meet?

Answer (score 1):

The first one, the one you see in developer.apple.com is usually your team prefix, it is used for provisioning.
The latter one, in iTunes Connect is an id used to identify the app in the App Store.